# C# LINQ ternary operator as a switchcase inside a foreach

Tags: c#, linq, switch-statement, ternary-operator

i am using LINQ and HtmlAgilitypack to create a datatable out of an HTML.
the following gets the html table headers and constructs the datatable columns:

```
var nodes = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table[@class='ps-sellers-table crts']/tr");
             nodes[0].Elements("th")
            .Skip(0)
            .Select(th => th.InnerText
            .Trim())
            .ToList()
            .ForEach(header => dt.Columns.Add(header));
```

so far its working perfectly except i need some customization.

1. chosing what columns to be added.
2. and specifying the column type.

this select statement will do the 2 things above:

```
switch (header)
            {
                case ("id") : dt.Columns.Add(header,typeof(int)); break;
                case ("name") : dt.Columns.Add(header,typeof(string)); break;
                case ("price") : dt.Columns.Add(header,typeof(decimal)); break;
                case ("shipping") : dt.Columns.Add(header,typeof(decimal)); break;
                default : //skip the column and dont add it
            }
```

however i am really new to LINQ and C#, and i want to implement the above switch case inside the foreach in the first snippet, i know i should use `ternary operator`, but i am not sure about the sytax.

Comment: Why not write a method that uses the switch block and call the method instead?

Comment: I agree with torrential, over-abusing the ternary operator makes code messy and barely readable.  A method containing the logic is far more readable (and testable if public!).  I personally only use ternary operators with booleans.

Comment: It looks like you have a simple mapping between column name and type. Why not just use a `Dictionary<string,Type>`?

Comment: @ThomSmith maybe because i don't know what that is yet, as i am still learning!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would wrap the switch into a method, and then call the method from within your select statement.

My version would look like:

```
var nodes = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table[@class='ps-sellers-table crts']/tr");
         nodes[0].Elements("th")
        .Select(th => th.InnerText.Trim());

foreach(var node in nodes)
    AddColumnToDataTable(node, dt);
```

Note that there's no need to `Skip(0)`, and calling `ToList()` just to use `List<T>.ForEach` reduces readability and adds overhead.  I personally prefer just using a normal `foreach`.

That being said, your method could be refactored into using a `Dictionary<string, Type>` instead.  If you add this to your class:

```
Dictionary<string, Type> typeLookup;
// In your constructor:

public YourClass()
{
    typeLookup.Add("id", typeof(int));
    typeLookup.Add("name", typeof(string));
    typeLookup.Add("price", typeof(decimal));
    typeLookup.Add("shipping", typeof(decimal));
}
```

You could then write your method as:

```
void AddColumnToDataTable(string columnName, DataTable table)
{
    table.Columns.Add(columnName, typeLookup[columnName]);
}
```

Comment: You could use `Aggregate(dt, (table, header) => dt.Columns.Add(header))` directly on the `IEnumerable` to avoid the confusion of a `ToList` call

Comment: @just.another.programmer I avoided the `ToList` call here anyways.  In general, I like to avoid LINQ statements which perform side effects - any call to a method like "Add" within a LINQ query screams of a bad practice...  That being said, there's no need for `Aggregate` if you want to do that - a simple `Select` will work just as well...

Comment: just a little question, about ignoring a column using the where clause, is the following alright? `nodes[0].Elements("th").Select(th => th.InnerText.Trim()).Where(th => th != "somecolumn");`

Answer (score 1):

You could just add the switch to the foreach, not sure why you have to use the ternary operator

```
.ToList().ForEach(header =>
{
    switch (header)
    {
       case ("id"): dt.Columns.Add(header, typeof(int)); break;
       case ("name"): dt.Columns.Add(header, typeof(string)); break;
       case ("price"): dt.Columns.Add(header, typeof(decimal)); break;
       case ("shipping"): dt.Columns.Add(header, typeof(decimal)); break;
       default: break; //skip the column and dont add it
    }
});
```